# Export NDWI of a Collection into single image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, normalized-difference-water-index

I am calculating the NDWI index for the image collection (4 months). Now I would like to export the maximum water extent for 4 months into one single image. I tried to use the ee.reduce.max(), but it seems like the are many noise pixels in the final product. How can I fix it?

Here is my code (https://code.earthengine.google.com/76be625187291fdfb49009be849ed125):

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0").filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Pakistan'));
Map.addLayer(roi, {color: 'black'}, 'Study Area',1);
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);

var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('1998-06-01', '1998-10-1')
                  .filterBounds(roi);
                  
var clouds_free = dataset.map(cloudMaskL457);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

Map.addLayer(clouds_free.median(), visParams);
var decision_tree = function(image){
  var mndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B2', 'B5']);
  var evi = image.expression(
    '(NIR - RED)/(NIR+6*RED-7.5*BLUE+1)*2.5', {
      'BLUE': image.select('B1'),
      'RED': image.select('B3'),
      'NIR': image.select('B4'),
    });
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']);
  var lswi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B5']);
  var water = evi.lt(0.1).and(mndwi.gt(evi).or(mndwi.gt(ndvi))).rename('water');
  //var vegetation = evi.gte(0.1).and (ndvi.gte(0.2)).and (lswi.gt(0)).rename('vegetation');
  return water.copyProperties(image);  
};

var result = clouds_free.map(decision_tree)
var water_mask = result.select('water').reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
Map.addLayer(result)
Map.addLayer(water_mask)
```